# Android - Can't see the menu option at a fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I've bumped into something I don't understand.

I'm using the next layout XML code -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/faq_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see it only contains a WebView.

Now I've created a class as follows:

```
public class FaqFrag extends Fragment{



public FaqFrag(){}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);


}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_lay, container, false);
    WebView wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.faq_webview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.something.com");



    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.faq_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     switch (item.getItemId()) {

     case R.id.send_feedback:

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"botnapp@gmail.com"});        

            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

         return true;

     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



     }

}

}
```

Also I've made the next menu xml file -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item android:id="@+id/send_feedback"
          android:icon="@drawable/send_feedback_ico"
          android:title="@string/send_feedback_menu"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Now the weird thing is that when I'm running the app I can't see the menu button at all.
I've used this code before at a diffrent fragment and all was fine.

Just to be clear this fragment is shown aftr a click at a Navigation Drawer, so there's an action bar where the menu button should be shown.

Any one have an idea why isn't this working?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in `onCreate()`.