# Why don't I open option menu by click a button when I use ActionBarActivity in android?

Tags: android-studio

I can open option menu using the code `openOptionsMenu()` while I click a button if I use Action, now I use the class ActionBarActivity instead of  Action,
I find  `openOptionsMenu()` don't work, and option menu can't be opened, why?  Thanks!

To Jared Burrows :

A: Why do you need this functionality?

Q: Because I need to open Option Menu by clicking **More...** button

[image]

```
package com.example.cuiwei.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openOptionsMenu();
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="158dp" />

</RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cuiwei.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Before anyone looks at this, you should be using `AppCompatActivity`. But what are you trying to accomplish why doing this?

Comment: Thanks! just now I use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivit , but I get the same result, openOptionsMenu() don't work yet!

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I need the functionality, and before I worked well when I use Activity.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448144/android-cant-see-the-menu-option-at-a-fragment-layout, I can display option menu in fragment layout by adding the code setHasOptionsMenu(true); but how can I do that at ActionBarActivity ? Thanks!

Comment: To  Jared Burrows:  I have answered "why do you need the functionality", would you please see my modified question at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836794/why-dont-i-open-option-menu-by-click-a-button-when-i-use-actionbaractivity-in-a.Thanks!

Comment: popup menu can do that, but it require API 11, my min API is 9 :(  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: app compatv7 provides PopupMenu for API 7+. This is **exactly** why I asked you **why**. Stick to one question, stop copying and pasting the same comments back and forth.